# is it possible to add rank with pagination in mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb

```
db.user_stats.aggregate([{"$match":{"company_id":5}},{"$group":{"_id":"$item_id","review_count":{"$sum":"$review_count"},"avg_rating":{"$avg":"$avg_rating"},"item_id":{"$first":"$item_id"},"item_type":{"$first":"$item_type"},"company_id":{"$first":"$company_id"},"object_id":{"$first":"$_id"}}},{"$skip":0},{"$limit":20},{"$sort":{"review_count":1}}])
```

And the data is stored below

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "639c7103e687877baf0b2f57"
  },
  "review_count": 1,
  "avg_rating": 4,
  "item_id": 2,
  "item_type": "user",
  "company_id": 5,
  "created_date": "2022-12-16 11:47:01"
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "639c7103e687877baf0b2f57"
  },
  "review_count": 10,
  "avg_rating": 4,
  "item_id": 2,
  "item_type": "user",
  "company_id": 5,
  "created_date": "2022-12-16 11:47:01"
}
```

The Sorting and pagination are working correctly but we need to show the rank for every record with pagination.

The expected output

```
"items": {
            "totalCount": 2,
            "current": 1,
            "totalPages": 1,
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": "639c7103e687877baf0b2f57",
                    "item_id": 2,
                    "item_type": "team",
                    "item_title": "Team1",
                    "item_rank": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": "639c7103e687877baf0b2f51",
                    "item_id": 23,
                    "item_type": "team",
                    "item_rank": 2
                }
            ]
        }
```

The item_rank is based on the review_count.

Comment: What do you mean by "rank"?

Comment: rank based on certain column like review_count

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: Please check the description